# Sync Framework 2.1 - Large data over WCF

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have implemented data sync using MS Sync framework 2.1 over WCF to sync multiple SQL Express databases with a central SQL server. Syncing is happening every three minutes through a windows service. Recently, we noticed that huge amounts of data is being exchanged over the network (~100 MB every 15 minutes). When I checked using Fiddler, the client calls the service with a GetKnowledge request four times in a session and each response is around 6 MB in size, although there are no changes at all in either database. This does not seem to be normal? How do I optimize the system to reduce such heavy traffic? Please help.

I have defined two scopes with first one having 15 tables all download only. The second one has 3 tables with upload only direction.

The XML response has a very huge number of <range> tags under coreFragments/coreFragment/ranges tag which is the major portion contributing to the response size.

Let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must be the sync knowledge. do you do lots of deletes? or do you have lots of replicas? try running a metadata cleanup and see if it compacts the sync knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the response June! 
I am not sure what you meant by replicas, if you mean the SQL express clients, at the moment we have only two of them. Regarding metadata cleanup, how do we do that?

Comment: Also are you saying that this amount of knowledge data is normal?

Comment: the range values can become fragmented with lots of deletes...replica count is the number of copies synching together. the sync knowledge stores what was synched with which replica. see metadata cleanup here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617373(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: In normal operation we do not have any deletes, but it might be possible that the person deploying the system has deleted data. Is there anyway I can know if deletes have been done from the tracking tables? The metadata cleanup does not seem straightforward as if we cleanup some required data the system will start throwing exceptions. How can I know which metadata is relevant and which is not? Thanks.

Comment: if you only have two clients, metadata cleanup shouldnt be an issue since you can sync them first before you do the clean up. sync fx do not store deletes made on the tracking table itself. however,it's possible to figure out if the tracking tables were cleaned up manually. all rows in the table you're synching should have a corresponding row in the tracking table and if you include the delete metadata, the tracking table should have more rows than the base table.

Comment: Great, I will try that out. Can I just cleanup everytime after a sync, so it does not become a maintenance headache later? Also, what I meant regarding deletes is if it is possible to know from the tracking tables if data from the original tables were deleted?

Comment: if a row is deleted from the base table, the corresponding row in the tracking table should have the tombstone flag set.

Comment: Thanks for your continued support. I think I am moving in the right direction. One of the big tables with 3000+ rows has just one row deleted. But I found that another table has 94 rows but the tracking table has only 56. So this means the tracking table is corrupted. Does this have any implication on my original problem of huge knowledge data response?

Comment: Hi June, I am stuck. The metadata cleanup did not help. I guess the issue might be of large amount of unwanted knowledge being shared with all the clients. I am following a hub & spoke topology with 2 clients at the moment which can grow upto 60 clients soon. I read in MSDN that it is preferred to have separate scope per client to avoid contention but nothing is mentioned about knowledge size. Will having separate scopes help in size reduction? Is there any code sample on how to create separate scopes per client?

Comment: normally, 2 clients shouldn't be an issue. sync knowledge is kept per scope, so the more replicas it has to track, the more it has to store. if you have a one-to-one correspondence between client and server scope (each client has its own dedicated scope), then you're only tracking two replicas: the client and the server.

Comment: Thanks June! I have modified the system to create new scopes (two each per client) as and when a client syncs for the first time. After that I de-provisioned and provisioned the server and all the clients. All seems to be fine now. I am waiting for the data report from our customer to confirm the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Creating one to one scopes and re-provisioning fixed the issue. I am not still sure what caused the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have any join tables and use any ORM. If you do, then this post might help.

https://kumarkrish.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/microsoft-sync-frameworks-heavy-traffic/